# $a_{2014}$ sought in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n$ sequence is defined as follows: $a_1=0$ and $a_n$ is the smallest positive whole number, such that within $a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},a_n$ there is no arithmetic progression of 3 terms. How do I determine $a_{2014}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is related to one special case of an unproven conjecture by Erdos, which is equivalent to:
"For any $m > 2$, given a sequence $a_k$ containing no subsequences of length $m$ that are in arithmetic progression, the harmonic sum $\sum_k \frac{1}{a_k}$converges." 
The sequence you are looking at is one less than the the "greedy" sequence for $m=3$. That is known as Szkere's sequence.

I'm unsure whether this sub-case of the Erdos conjecture has been proven, but it probably has because of this interesting feature:

The sequence of $a_k$ you present consists of all numbers whose ternary (base 3) representation do not include the tigit (ternary digit) $2$.

Now we can find a_{2014} as follows:

There are 2 single-tigit numbers (0 and 1) in the sequence.  ($a_2 = 1$.) Then there are two 2-tigit  members (10 and 11) so that $a_4 = 11 = 4$ in base 10.
Then there are 4 3-digit numbers; $a_8 = 111 = 13$ in base 10.  You see the pattern:  If we take the terneray representation, which will have no 2's, of any $a_k$, then interpret those 1's and 0's as binary digits, we will have the binary representation of $k-1$.

Thus the binary representation of $2013$ will be the ternary representation of $a_{2014}$. So the ternary representation of $a_{2014}$ is $11111011101$.    In base ten,
$$
a_{2014} = 88327
$$

Comment: By the way, the $m=3$ case has indeed been proven:  Look at arXiv 1404.1557 by Gabor Korvin.

Comment: And in fact a closely related conjecture has also been proven,see the Korbin paper for discussion.